# PHP Mail function does not working on server

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email through php mail() function from my server. But it returning following error.

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()=
```

Can someone kindly guide me for this. I am not trying from xammp or wamp.

Comment: Have you setup smtp in your server?

Comment: @Thamilan That's what i don't know? I will have to setup ?

Comment: Yes, there should be mailing service in your cpanel or ask your hosting provider to help you out there. This option varies based on the plans they offer for you.

Comment: @Thamilan can you please let me know what  should i tell them ?